# Inconsistent SQLite timestamps

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm using two timestamps, `last_edited` and `last_uploaded`, to tell if a SQLite entry needs to be uploaded to my server. However, even though I'm using datetime('now') whenever I update these timestamps, the timestamp in `last_uploaded` is saved as my local time (UTC +2).

Any ideas on why this is or how I can fix it?

My SQLite statements are:

```
private static final String UPDATE_EDITED_TIMESTAMP_BY_ID =
      "UPDATE " + TABLE_ENTRIES + "\n"
    + "SET " + COLUMN_ENTRIES_LAST_EDITED + " = DATETIME('now')\n"
    + "WHERE " + COLUMN_ENTRIES_ID + " = :id;";

private static final String UPDATE_SYNC_INFO_BY_ID =
      "UPDATE " + TABLE_WORK_ENTRIES + "\n"
    + "SET " + COLUMN_ENTRIES_LAST_SYNCED + " = DATETIME('now'), " + COLUMN_ENTRIES_SERVER_ID + " = :server_id\n"
    + "WHERE " + COLUMN_ENTRIES_ID + " = :db_id;";
```

When I run them, I'm using code like:

```
String sql = UPDATE_EDITED_TIMESTAMP_BY_ID.replace(":id", Integer.toString(id));
db.execSQL(sql);
```

Comment: why are you using :id only to replace it later ? there is already a mechanism in android using '?' and the `args` param of the `db.update()` method.

Comment: explain `the timestamp in last_uploaded is being saved as localtime.`

Comment: @njzk2: I use :id just for readability of the SQL - that's just how I do it. About being saved at localtime, see the edit in my post.

Comment: I should also clarify - I know that the `:id` replacing isn't what's wrong.

Comment: that may be how you do it, but that's not what is recommended. The '?' mechanism in android allows sqlite to recognize identical queries and to properly escape arguments. you really should use it. Plus, the update method returns a value that gives you an indication as to the success of your query, while execSQL doesn't.

Comment: Then I'll definitely consider that. However, that's not the issue, because I'm checking the values before and after execution in the sqlite shell and it's definitely updating.

Comment: explain `the timestamp in last_uploaded is being saved as localtime.`. How do you observe that?

Comment: Say the time where I am is 8:00 AM. UTC, that would be 6 AM. When this code runs, instead of showing up as 6:00 am, the timestamp says 8:00. I need the timestamps to be in the same time zone so I can compare them.

Comment: timestamps are not timezone relative. they are always UTC. Timezone are added at display time.

Comment: Regardless of what should be happening, the `last_uploaded` timestamp is 2 hours ahead of the actual time in UTC.

Comment: my understanding is that datetime returns a string, which is a representation, and it may not contain the timezone. I would use a plain unix timestamp, and get it using System.currentTimeMillis() from the android part

Comment: I'll try that, and also switch to using update() wherever I can.

Comment: @njzk2: I did both things you suggested, and it's working now - Want to write an answer I can accept?